# How to schedule a data ingest from a 3rd party API into Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a Google Cloud Function that makes an API request and uploads the response as a JSON file to cloud storage. I'm running into an issue with larger requests because Google Cloud Functions time out after 540 seconds. This is causing my batch API requests to return an error.

What the best way to schedule large data transfers from a 3rd part API into google cloud storage?

Comment: Asking for a technology recommendation is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. But did you consider processing the data in chunks, so that each chunk fits within the maximum timeout of Cloud Functions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/overview). It can be scheduled and accepts as source Amazon S3 bucket, an HTTP/HTTPS location or another Cloud Storage bucket.